# image setting on uibutton in right side bottom

Tags: iphone, xcode

I  am having button of frame (0,0,120,100) and i want to add a image at right side of button 
.i want to add the image of size (10,10) which i want on right hand side in bottom of the button .

How to do this .I googled but could net get about it.

Comment: The answer was itself in your question... and KingOfBless has represented it in the nice way... +1 for dat KOB.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer is suppose say i have uibutton   roundedButtonType the code is as follows

```
        roundedButtonType = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
    [roundedButtonType setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10.00, 5.00, -5.00, 0.00)];
```

By doing this i cant get set image on button whereever  i want on the button .

By setting the background image of button earlier the image was getting streched . So i used the above code to get the click event for larger area (on button )which solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Code as follows,

```
UIButton *imageBut=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 120, 100)];
UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 90, 10, 10)];
img.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
[imageBut addSubview:img];
[self.view addSubview:imageBut];
```

x,y is the position of the button in your view.